# Creating tables in Oracle database by JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have problem with creating tables by JDBC controller on Oracle database.
When I create table by "creata table...." is ok. Table create and I see that table by SQL Developer. I have method to check if table with that name exist - and it works good.
So when I create table (I try to do commit, too - do not help), table appear in SQL developer but when i check by my method if that table exist i get 'false' (do not exist), when I restart database and run again, my method return 'true'.
I think is a problem with session but I don't now how to get over with that.

```
enter code here public void prepStatExecuteCreateTable(String name){
        String createTable= "Create table "+ name +"  (ID NUMBER(*, 0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, CZAS NUMBER(*, 0) NOT NULL, OTWARCIE   NUMBER(6, 2) NOT NULL , MAX_KURS   NUMBER(6, 2) NOT NULL , MIN_KURS   NUMBER(6, 2) NOT NULL , ZAMKNIECIE NUMBER(6, 2) NOT NULL , VOLUMEN    NUMBER(*, 0) NOT NULL , FOREIGN KEY(czas) references CZAS(ID))";
        PreparedStatement ps=null;
    try{
        ps = returnConnection().prepareStatement(createTable);

    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Error with preperadStatement(create table): "+ e.getMessage());
    }

    try{
        ps.execute();

        returnConnection().commit();
        ps.close();
        closeConnection();
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Error with execute: "+ e.getMessage());
    }

}


public boolean ifExistTable(String tablename) throws SQLException{
    String sql = "Select TABLE_NAME from user_tables where table_name='"+tablename.toUpperCase()+"' ";  
    System.out.println(sql);
    ResultSet rs =null;
    Statement ps = null;
    try{
        ps = returnConnection().createStatement();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Error with preperadSatement(checking): "+ e.getMessage());
    }
    try{
        rs=ps.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()){
                System.out.println (rs.getString(1));   // Print col 1
                    if(rs.getString(1).equals(tablename)){
                            return true;
                    }
            }
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Error with executing checking " +e.getMessage()+ " " + e.getStackTrace());
    }
    ps.close();
    return false;
}
```

this is how I use in the Main method: (condDB is a object that has above methods)

```
enter code here String table_name="BBB";
    System.out.println(conDB.ifExistTable(table_name));
    conDB.prepStatExecuteCreateTable(table_name);
```

so if I run first, I get message "false" (table do not exist)
and is created (check by SQL developer, table with name 'BBB' appear)
when I run secondly I get message "false" and error message from second method: 
Error with execute: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your rights. Your procedure can't see the table because it doesn't have the rights to see it.

Comment: Can we see the code that creates the table and the code that checks whether it exists?

Comment: @Matthew Farwell: I don't think so. When he restarts the database, the procedure sees the table...

Comment: I don't think so, that this is problem with rights because my   procedure see that tables (that new created) if I restart database (created earlier see without restart)

Comment: @user1055201 - Can you show an example of `ifExistTable` seeing that the table does not exist, a call to `prepStatExecuteCreateTable` creating the table, and then a subsequent call to `ifExistTable` showing that the table still appears not to exist?  I believe that's what you're saying that you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

1) Your `ifExistTable` function really ought to be using bind variables rather than building the SQL statement using string concatenation if only to avoid SQL injection attacks.

2) Your `ifExistTable` function is running a query that uses the upper-case value of the `tablename` that is passed in.  But then when you're fetching the data from `rs`, you're making a case-sensitive comparison with `rs.getString(1).equals(tablename)`.  At a minimum, that ought to be `equalsIgnoreCase`.  But there should be no need to do the comparison at all in Java since your SQL statement is already doing it.  If the `ResultSet` has a row, the table exists (or you can write the query as a `COUNT(*)` and check to see whether the row that is returned has a value of '1').

Comment: I don't carry on SQL injection because this is for my own use:) 
upper-case I use because oracle use upper case in table name always (in sql statment is irrelevant)

Comment: @user1055201 - Table names will be stored in upper case in the data dictionary assuming you are not using case-sensitive identifiers.  But in the code where you are fetching from the result set, you are doing a case-sensitive comparison.  If the table name passed in to the function is not upper case, the `equals` comparison will fail despite the fact that the query determined that the table does in fact exist.

Comment: I have checked and You have right.
It was funny-stupid bug.
So for others: When I try to create table with name e.g. 'kkkk' Oracle developer show this name like 'KKKK' and if I check if table with name 'kkkk' exist I get 'false'.  
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps when you created your stored procedure inside the package, you didn't close it with '/'

```
...
END;
/
```

so the connection is stucked and the resource is not liberated to be used by other query (which is actually another logical connection). commit will not work as you are performing a DDL sentence which could care less about commiting hehehe